# What are symbols with (.cold.n) in object files built for iOS?

Tags: c++, xcode

I am working on a multiplatform library that is compiled as static library for iOS. After a seemingly unrelated change the binary for iOS became significantly larger. When I looked at contents of the library to see what had changed, I saw a large number symbols with demangled names like this:

```
unsigned short boost::basic_format<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::make_or_reuse_data(unsigned long) (.cold.1)
```

I understand that the duplication is because the Boost formatter is included in many object files, but what is interesting is the (.cold.1) part. This particular function does not have any other versions, but there are some that come both without the part and .cold. versions with numbers up to 8.

What does the .cold. and number mean, and does the increased library size transfer to final app binary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same question, then I google it.
I guess that `__attribute__((cold))` is the cause of `.cold.n` appending to the method name.

---

Reference

- [[llvm-dev] [RFC] Add "hot" function attribute to LLVM IR and use
  hot/cold attribute in function section prefix](https://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2020-December/147104.html)
- [6.30 Declaring Attributes of Functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html)
- [Line64 in attributes.h](https://libav.org/documentation/doxygen/master/attributes_8h_source.html)

Comment: The codebase itself or its direct dependencies doesn't use __attribute__(cold) or hot, but maybe the compiler is generating these on its own.